# sendToBack / sendBawark does not hide the object to against the other object Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am working on fabric.js and canvas. I am using the properties of fabric.js sendToBack / sendBaward but it deos not work for me. I want that when I click on button send to back the current active object goes to behind the other object. My working link is below.

[Cap Customizer](http://production.technology-architects.com/ADIL/cape_customizer_wp/customizer/)

And the code snip is below.

```html
function moveBack()
{
 var sel_obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 if(sel_obj)
 {
  console.log('back');
  canvas.sendToBack(sel_obj);
  canvas.renderAll();
 }
}
```

Anyone can know please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You missinterpreted `sendToBack` method. It applies on the object, not on the canvas, according to this [doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html).

You should therefore either use `sendToBack`to move your selected object at the bottom of the drawn objects' stack, or `sendBackwards(true)` to send it only behind the first lower object drawn.

In both cases you need to use the method on the **object** and not the **canvas**. If you need any explanaitions let me know in comment, but please read the linked doc before.

Comment: i read the document but can't understand how i can apply in my case sendToBack / sendBackwards(true) and bringToFront is not working

Comment: Replace `canvas.sendToBack(sel_obj)` with `sel_obj.sendToBack()` . This is literally what I conclude my answer with.

Comment: I also try like this sel_obj.sendToBack() but it also not work for me.

Comment: I dont know why?

Comment: According to the doc, `sendToBack()`sends your target to the bottom of drawn objects pile. If it doesn't provide the result you expect, you might want to investigate about your canvas properties & settings, because it should.

Comment: I tried many ways and methods many days but i cant get success. I want like this "https://www.rageon.com/pages/builder"